# Using remote network address using draytek lan to lan vpn

Tags: networking, router, vpn, draytek

I have a puzzle to solve, probably a trivial one, something is dawning on me somewhere, but not entirely.
but to the point:

I have 2 draytek routers connected to each other using a VPN tunnel (lan-to-lan). Now I would like to move the machine that is connected to router B from the 192.168.10.0 network to router A from the 192.168.15.0 network so that this machine retains the address of the first one mentioned.  networks (specifically 192.168.10.250) and was available for networks A and B. I have already tried to play with routing using the above-mentioned VPN as an "interface", but it doesn't work very well

I will be grateful for your help!

Comment: this really isn't worth trying. why do you want to do that? lets talk about what you actually want to do before talking about how to do it.

Comment: I noted that the OP can use Client to Site mode to allow it to move around. That works.

Comment: Well my client is forcing me to move server from town to town and changing server's IP will be painful to fix

Comment: what kind of a server is it? do you refer to it by DNS names? how many clients and are they under your control? so even if you stitch together a VPN loop, traffic coming from the .15. network would cross the VPN to .10. and then get sent back across the VPN to the origin network. the server would need a valid address from .15. to participate in a VPN connecting anyway, and would receive its .10. address fromt he client2site VPN connection. i also don't think the clients on .10. would be able to access the server, since they reach systems in .10. without going through a router. so lots of bad.

Answer (score 0):

A VPN endpoint has either one IP address or one Subnet for the endpoint addressing. So trying to add a different subnet to one endpoint will not work.  (>95%).

I imagine the VPN is having issues with your setup so it may be difficult to know what errors are occurring.

**(A)** You could try to set up Client to Site mode for the "moveable" computer so it can connect from anywhere.

**(B)** You might also put a router at each end so the router connects to the site VPN and then hands out addresses to the client computers. I think this might work because no computer would be connected directly to the VPN endpoint.

Comment: So is there any other way to get what I want? As a last resort, I will have to change the server address, but it will be hard work ;)

Comment: I have done lots of work with VPN over the years and, yes, you will have to change addressing. I don't know of any other way.  You can set up the moveable computer Client to Site mode and that should work.

Comment: I also think you could add  a router at each end to isolate computers from the VPN endpoint. Answer amended.

Comment: Okay I'll I will check how client to site will work I hope it will be Enough ;) Thanks for help

Comment: I have given that an done other option. I hope you will recognize my answer as helpful